# mat-badge dont appear in mat-toolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material, badge

I have a mat-icon with badge that i want to display in a toolbar .
The problem is that the badge dont appear, but when I place inside the page everything works fine. I did not modify any css property. I have provided a screenshot.
Can anyone give a solution ?

tool-bar html :

```
<mat-toolbar role="heading" class="main-nav">
  <button class="btn" (click)="toggleSideNav()">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </button>

  <span class="toolbar-spacer"></span>

  <a style="color:black;" routerLink="commandeProduit/shopping/cart">
    <mat-icon class="cart" matBadge="1" matBadgePosition="above before"
      >add_shopping_cart</mat-icon
    >
  </a>

  <app-user-bar></app-user-bar>
</mat-toolbar>
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCuUd.png)

Comment: Do you give it value or through a variable?

Comment: no just testing for now